# removing the label on MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know the correct way to remove the label which is included at the top of each form. This is especially annoying when i have a pop-up form which contains this label containing the name of the form itself. I would like to remove it completely.

Comment: Also examine the form's Border Style property (found on the Format tab of the form's property sheet).  Setting Border Style to None hides the form's title bar --- which is otherwise where the form's Caption is displayed.  However that setting has other side effects which you may not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two choices:

1. Change the 'Caption' value to a space, or
2. Add code in the Form_Load event for

   Me.Caption = " "    ' NOTE! Include a space between the quotes

Comment: We are getting close. Unfortunately, using the double quotation marks "" makes no change however if i do Me.Caption="x" the forms label at the top is 'x'..   It seems that a complete blank value is not accepted

Comment: You saved me again Wayne. Thanks. .It looks like you are celebrating an anniversary. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a backup copy.

Can't you delete it using the design GUI? Right click on the form, select "Design View". Then select the label, right click and select 'Delete' from the context menu.

Comment: Sorry, what is a design GUI?

Comment: An Access application is developed using the same GUI you run the app in. By design GUI i just mean the application in design mode. You get into design mode by right-clicking on a form, and selecting 'Design View'. 

I presume you can modify the application and understand the Access development process and tools since you're asking this question.